# how to get RSSI information of WiFi users in wireshark?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, wireshark, packet-analysis

If I'm able to get 802.11n traffic with my network adapter, would I be able to see the RSSI information? what should be the filter to see it?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

RSSI value is not in the 802.11 packet. It’s determined by the receiver, and every manufacturer will determine it differently.

Comment: Depending on the definition of RSSI used, you [can get RSSI in wireshark packets](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/18484/viewing-rssi-value-in-wireshark) assuming your NIC driver (doing the capture) supports radiotap headers.

Comment: thank you @MikePennington. I also found these display filters: wlan_radio.signal_dbm, wlan.ta == <mac address>